# Passing radio button selection from main activity to second activity -- Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

My main activity has two Double inputs and two radio groups. I can pass the Double inputs from Main to second activity, but I don't know how to pass radio button selection.

For the Double inputs, this is what I have in Main Activity:

```
override fun onClick(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("score1", et1.text.toString().toDouble())
    intent.putExtra("score2", et2.text.toString().toDouble())

    startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
}
```

This is what I have in Second Activity:

```
val intent = intent
    var result: Double = 0.0
    val a = intent.getDoubleExtra("score1", 0.0)
    val b = intent.getDoubleExtra("score2", 0.0)

    result = a + b
```

How would I pass radio buttons to Second Activity?

rbgroup1 has two options: Black & White and rbgroup2 has 4 options: Fall, Spring, Summer, and Winter. The goal is an if statement in Second Activity that would look something like this:

```
If (rbBlack.isChecked) {
//do xyz
}else {
do abc}
```

Then

```
 If (rbFall.isChecked) {
//do xyz
}else if (rbSpring.isChecked){
do abc
}else if(rbSummer.isChecked){
do blah blah
}else blah
```

Comment: You can either put a `String` extra with a predefined value like `"fall"`, `"spring"`, ... into the intent or for each radio button a boolean extra with the `isChecked` state of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that when you select a Radio Button it places text on a Regular Button

XML code First

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvValOne"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Value One"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvValTwo"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Value Two"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvValOne"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvValOne" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvANS"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Answer"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textColor="@color/color_deepBlue"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvValTwo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvValTwo" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3203125" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etValOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etValTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etValOne" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etANS"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etValTwo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLAMmultiply"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:onClick="onLAMmultiply"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="Select Function"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Purple"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etANS" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:onClick="onBACK"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Purple"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvError"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/color_Red"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLAMmultiply" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value Addition"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Purple"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSubtract"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value Subtraction"
        android:textColor="@color/color_deepBlue"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbMultiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value Multiplication"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Red"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbDivision"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Value Division"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Yellow"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RadioGroup>
```

Now the Activity

```
class PageThreeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var MathFunction:String = ""

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_three)

    rgRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( { group, checkedId ->
        if (checkedId != -1) {
            MathFunction = (findViewById<View>(checkedId) as RadioButton).getText().toString()
            btnLAMmultiply.setText(MathFunction)

        } else {
            MathFunction = ""
            btnLAMmultiply.setText("Math Function")

        }
    })

}// end onCreate


fun doFunction(view: View){

    val id = rgRadioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId

    when (id) {
        R.id.rbAdd -> add(view)
        R.id.rbSubtract -> subtract(view)
        R.id.rbMultiply -> multiply(view)
        R.id.rbDivision ->division(view)
        else -> onLAMmultiply(view)
    }
}

fun add(view: View){
    val X = etValOne.text.toString()
    val Y = etValTwo.text.toString()
    val multB = {X:Double,Y:Double -> X.plus(Y)}
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")
    //val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()))
    etANS.setText(df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble())).toString())
    //etANS.setText(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()).toString())
}

fun subtract(view: View){
    val X = etValOne.text.toString()
    val Y = etValTwo.text.toString()
    val multB = {X:Double,Y:Double -> X.minus(Y)}
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")
    //val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()))
    etANS.setText(df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble())).toString())
    //etANS.setText(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()).toString())
}

fun multiply(view: View){
    val X = etValOne.text.toString()
    val Y = etValTwo.text.toString()
    val multB = {X:Double,Y:Double -> X.times(Y)}
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")// Show Two Decimal places with trailing ZERO
    //val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")// Show Two Decimal places no trailing Zero
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()))
    etANS.setText(df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble())).toString())
    //etANS.setText(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()).toString())
}

fun division(view: View){
    val X = etValOne.text.toString()
    val Y = etValTwo.text.toString()
    val multB = {X:Double,Y:Double -> X.div(Y)}
    val df = DecimalFormat("0.00")
    //val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()))
    etANS.setText(df.format(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble())).toString())
    //etANS.setText(multB(X.toDouble(),Y.toDouble()).toString())
}

fun onLAMmultiply(view: View ){

    if(etValOne.text.length == 0){
        error("Enter First Value")
        //toast("Enter First Value")
        etValOne.requestFocus()
        return@onLAMmultiply
    }

    if(etValTwo.text.length == 0){
        error("Enter Second Value")
        //toast("Enter Second Value")
        etValTwo.requestFocus()
        return@onLAMmultiply
    }

    if(rgRadioGroup.checkedRadioButtonId == -1){
        error("SELECT A FUNCTION")
        return@onLAMmultiply
    }

    doFunction(view)
}

fun Context.toast(message: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

fun error(msg:String){
    object : CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            tvError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            tvError.setText(msg)
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            tvError.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            tvError.setText("")
        }
    }.start()
}

fun onBACK(view: View){
    val intent = Intent(this@PageThreeActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

// End of Class
}

Because we shared so much code look at this in XML`android:id="@+id/btnLAMmultiply"

`

And this in the Activity

```
        rgRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( { group, checkedId ->
        if (checkedId != -1) {
            MathFunction = (findViewById<View>(checkedId) as RadioButton).getText().toString()
            btnLAMmultiply.setText(MathFunction)

        } else {
            MathFunction = ""
            btnLAMmultiply.setText("Math Function")

        }
    })

}// end onCreate
```

Welcome to Stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you! What about the code for the Main Activity?